# Lottie file issue in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, lottie

We have implemented a Lottie file in React JS code using the react-lottie-player. This Lottie file works fine when we test in our local machine but it fails when we deploy our code to any higher environments. We get the below error in console:

***TypeError: this.element[e].destroy is not a function***

What can be the issue here ?

Comment: Maybe you could reproduce it on https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: This issue happens when your lottie animations have expressions and your web server security policy doesn't allow unsafe-eval (lottie-web uses eval for expressions to work)